# Structure of valuations on $\mathbb{F}_q(X,Y)$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I'm looking to construct all valuations on $\mathbb{Q}(X,Y)$ extending the p-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ and understand their structural properties. In doing this, to obtain 3 dimensional valuation domains, I hope to obtain them via a series of pullbacks from the residue field maps. One of the residue fields involved will be $\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$, and I am hoping to find 1 and 2 dimensional valuation rings inside those. Are there any references I should read on this subject? Are there any theorems established on this topic?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I seem to remember figuring out that there are four kinds of $k$-valuations on $k(x,y)$ where $k$ is a field (perhaps algebraically closed?): (0) the generic point (i.e., the trivial valuation), (1) the generic point of curves (corresponding to discrete valuations), (2) closed points on curves (valuations of height $2$, with value group $\mathbb{Z}^2$) (amazingly, each such point lies on a unique curve), and (3) valuations of height $1$ but rational rank $2$, which correspond to sequences of blowups. (contd.)

Comment: Anyway, the term for the set of $k$-valuations on $K$ (here $k(x,y)$) is the "Zariski space" (or sometimes Zariski-Riemann space) of $K$.  The points of kind (3) in my previous comment can be described, I think, by points of Hironaka's so-called "voûte étoilée" construction (namely, elements of the projective system of blowups of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at points). These keywords might at least get you somewhere. Or you might want to try looking at: Favre & Jonsson, *The Valuative Tree* (Springer 2004) (it's for $k=\mathbb{C}$ but much should apply).

Comment: PS: I misremembered or messed up the classification (either I forgot some cases or I merged some), but the correct version is in Zariski's 1939 paper cited in the Wikipedia page "Zariski–Riemann space".